# Problem rewriting dynamic URLs using mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a dynamic URL using the following code:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ index.php?location=$1  
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?location=$1&company=$2
```

I really need two rewrites as you can see from the above code. First, I need the page to rewrite just the location if that's all there is. For example, it would turn site.ccom/index.php?location=sandiego into site.com/sandiego/
This is working correctly.

However, when I try to add in the second variable it fails. It manages to detect the &company=1 variable, but for some reason it returns the ?location=sandiego variable as 'index.php'. For example, if I input the following: site.com/san-diego/1/ and then try to grab the $location and $company variables, it will only get the $company variable successfully, and the $location variable will be set to 'index.php', rather than 'san-diego'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I'm using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?location=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?location=$1&company=$2 [NC]
```

This seems to be working perfectly, and is successfully redirecting both site.com/sandiego/ and site.com/sandiego/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try those:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$    index.php?location=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?.*$    index.php?location=$1&company=$2 [NC]
```

Keep in mind that trying to capture any sequence of characters (by using for example `(.*)` or `(.+)`) when doing URL rewriting, is usually a bad idea, as explained in this thread : http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/apache-configuration-199/rewrite-eliminate-trailing-slash-arbitrary-parameters-520302.html#post3657601

Comment: Sorry, neither of those work at all. They both returned with 404 errors.

Comment: Sorry, I've renamed `index.php` to `rewrite.php` for testing and forgot to change that back... => edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, a figured that, and renamed to index.php. It still doesn't work however. Going back to my original code, I can get either one or the other to work. If I just use this line: `RewriteRule (.*)/$ index.php?location=$1` it redirects site.com/sandiego/ perfectly. And if I use just this line: `RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?location=$1&company=$2` it redirects to site.com/sandiego/1/ perfectly. However, when I use them together it all breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try  ([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/$  instead of (.*)/(.*)/$
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think I've solved the problem (posted below). I will get back to you if my solution doesn't work, and will test your approach. Thanks again.